# Is there any API to get the information about the component that triggered the BundleSaveArgs event?

Tags: event-system

BundleSaveEvent gets triggered when a component/page is added to the bundle.

Is there a way to get only the current component/page which got added to the bundle and raised the BundleSaveEvent?

I am able to get the list of items within the bundle through the Bundle object, but I only need the single component that triggered the BundleSaveEvent.

BundleSaveEventArgs.ItemsAdded returns null :(

Comment: Are you looking during `Initiated` phase or `Processed` phase of the event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BundleSaveEventArgs` has `ItemsAdded` and `ItemsRemoved` property which contains info about what items have been added and/or removed from the bundle.

Comment: Am using Tridion 2013 and these two properties are not populated. I have already tried this.

Comment: I put in a comment in your question. Are you looking during `Initiated` phase or `Processed` phase of the event? As it is expected to be null/empty in the `Initiated` phase.

Comment: Thanks LiKhan. Processed eventphase populated the ItemsAdded and ItemsRemoved property.